# How to get boundary value of rect tag in svg using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, svg-edit

I am working in svg editor 2.7 version,Here i need to selected individual boundary value of rectangle in svg using javascript.

> ```
> <svg width="9000" height="100" style="border:1px solid black">
> <rect x="9000" y="0" height="100" width="200"></rect>
> </svg>
> ```

[image: RECTANGLE ORIGINAL]

My rectangle getting this selected tool.But i need to select individual corner of rectangle as below images

[image: RECTANGLE RESULT]

In svg edit files contain mousedown,mousemove and mouseup event.Here i used `GETBBOX()` function to get boundary value. but i need to split boundary for selection like above image 2.
Here am working on mouseover event for getting boundary of rectangle in svg. but i didn't achieve it. kindly guide me for this or drag me into right way.

```
var mouseOver = function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var root_sctm = $('#svgcontent g')[0].getScreenCTM().inverse();
        var pt = svgedit.math.transformPoint( evt.pageX, evt.pageY, root_sctm ),
        mouse_x = pt.x * current_zoom,
        mouse_y = pt.y * current_zoom;
        var x = mouse_x / current_zoom,
        y = mouse_y / current_zoom,
        mouse_target = getMouseTarget(evt);
        mouse_target =selectedElements[0];
    switch (current_mode) {

            case 'rect':
                var test =selectedElements[0].getBBox();
                console.log(test);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: If you are trying to determine which edge of the rectangle you are near, then you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` and then use those coords to test whether the mouse x,y is close to any of the four edges.

Comment: @BigBadaboom..I really tried to find edge of the rectangle but i can't achieve it..Can you please clarify much more elaboration? or else provide some other solution for this?

Comment: Show us the code for what you have tried so far, and we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: @BigBadaboom.. i working in that demo coding: http://pastebin.com/1vGNeVuC,

Comment: HI @BigBadaboom..are u analysis about my code...?
Note: I working on svg editor2.7 https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/...

Comment: It looks like you just copied the above code to pastebin.  That's not what I meant.  I meant something like a demo in jsfiddle.net showing some "working" code.

Comment: @BigBadaboom... Here i worked in svg editor js file.it seems to know how to create demo in jsfiddle.net.. i provide my working demo website url for    your convenience..http://www.floordraw.osiztechnologies.com/floordraw/tool..  Let choose third tab button and draw rectangle section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an UI issue, not coding.

1. On mouseenter() `<rect>`, outline the box using 4 `<line>` and overlay it over the <rect>`.
2. Attach `mousedown()` and `mousemove()` event listener to all 4 lines, so you can actually click on them and drag them around.
3. Update the `<rect>` x, y, width AND height values whenever one edge is dragged.
4. On mouseleave(), destroy these 4 lines and remove the event listener.

This skips the calculation of which edge is nearest to mouse.

Snap SVG or RaphaelJS can be used to implement this UI, saves you some low level coding.

Comment: Thank your valuable response @Alvin K. but i using SVG EDITOR 2.7.I am using to svg rect tag and modified it.but one thing, i convert rect tag into line tag meant i face any another problem based on svg editor.I would get rectangle x,y,width and height value by using this method getBBox() same like any method that get individual boundary values for rectangle in svg editor 2.7?

Comment: svg-edit has features that I didn't like and my own UI tweak is explained above. Also `getBBox()` gives different values between browsers, not svg-edit fault but it messes up the precision.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood well what you asked.

If you want to get boundaries of an element you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`  function for javascript

ex:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0].getBoundingClientRect()
 document.getElementsByTagName('rect')[1].getBoundingClientRect()
```

This will give you  `width`, `height`, `left`, `top`, `bottom` and `right` values

If you want to select margins of the rect, I think that's not possible and you have to build your rect with `svg-lines`

Comment: Hi @Kosmo..I try getBoundingClientRect() function also..any other method to get edges of rectangle.?it not possible ah?